# How do I exclude sub-pages from a page loop?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

This is what I have so far. Unfortunately this grabs **ALL** my pages' titles and content including sub-pages. I only want to display top-level main pages. How can I do this?

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=page'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
         <?php the_title(); ?>
         <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

*Note: I want to display both title and content for the pages. Not just title. Otherwise I would use:

```
<?php wp_list_pages('depth=1'); ?>
```

UPDATE: Following konsolenfreddy's advice I was able to loop through my pages properly. However a new problem arose. The content is being striped of its tags. Anyway I can keep them? Here's my new code:

```
<?php 
  $pages = get_pages('parent=0'); 
  foreach ($pages as $pagg) {
    $option .= $pagg->post_title;
    $option .= $pagg->post_content;
  echo $option;
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_pages()` (see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages ), it takes the same arguments as `wp_list_pages()`

Comment: Thank you for the help. Your advice worked. But a new problem came up that I could use some more help with. My post above has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=page&post_parent='.$parent);?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
         <?php the_title(); ?>
         <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: No, but I've updated my original question. I found a working solution, but the solution is having another issue